# Derive Formula for factorials summation.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

What will be the **unit** digit in $\sum_{k=1}^nk!$ ?

$$1! + 2!  +3! + 4! + ........ + n!$$

Formula for the Summation of combination of **N** Number is $2^n$ but formula for Factorials And permutation of **N** numbers becomes hard .

*Is there Any formula  or shortcut for This?*

Comment: Hint : $n!$ ends in zero after some time. But in general, factorial sums will involve transcendental functions, so calculating these is difficult.

Comment: For the record, $\sum_{k=1}^n k!$ does not simplify. See [A007489](https://oeis.org/A007489) on OEIS. It is, however, D-finite and the exponential generating function satisfies a nice first order differential equation. See [A003422](https://oeis.org/A003422) for a very similar sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Every factorial $n!$ ends with $0$, for $n\ge 5$. i.e. $$5!=120, 6!=720, 7!=5040, \ \text{etc}$$

Comment: But the Question is what will be outcome after summation of all n! numbers. what if i got summation of upto 49!

Comment: As per the question, you only require the **unit** digit, not the actual outcome, and the **unit** digit of the sum only depends on the *unit digits of the individual terms in the sum*.

Comment: The units digit in the sum $$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+\cdots$$ is the same as the units digit in the sum $$1!+2!+3!+4!$$ because the terms after that have $0$ in their units place, and the unit digit in the second sum is not $1$. 

There is no *elementary* formula for the sum of factorials, as mentioned by @Teresa Lisbon in the comments, it can be done by using integrals as mentioned [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-sum-of-factorials-1-2-3-n#268691).